# Success message not showing in safari browser

Tags: success-message, safari

We are using Magento 2.4.6 version and facing an issue on cart page. When we delete a product it shows a message, Product removed successfully. But in case of Safari, it doesn't show the success message. Even that message div is not showing.

Please reply.

Comment: I think you have a caching issue you need to check in another browser